# CheckSelfPermission always returning PERMISSION_GRANTED even though targeting SDK 23

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am trying to implement the finger print scanner and I am first checking permission so that I can then get the users permission.

I have the following code:

```
int permissionState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SecurityPicker.this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT);
        Log.d("SecrityPicker", String.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SecurityPicker.this, Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SecurityPicker.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT},
                    MY_PERMISSION_USE_FINGERPRINT);
        }
        else
        {
            fingerPrintContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

The checkSelfPermission is always returning permission granted even though I haven't. The Android emulator I am using API 23 (Marshmallow).

Below is my gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0-rc1"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 33
        versionName "2.0.1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            debuggable false
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to check run time permission for permissions whose Protection Level is **dangerous**.

The `Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT` has a Protection Level of **Normal** as can be seen [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#USE_FINGERPRINT). Hence it is not required to get that permission at run time.

For **Normal** level permissions, it is enough to just specify them in the manifest. That is the reason that you are getting the permission result always granted.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) for more detail about which permission is dangerous.

Comment: Ah I didn't see that, I was looking at a code example for the fingerprint use and they did this check so thought all permissions needed to be checked